# Printing utf8 characters from utf8 codes in Go

Tags: go, utf-8

**Problem:**
I am trying to retrieve the value of a utf8 code designation.

let's say we have this situation:

```
//String with the alphabet and some numbers.
var aMess string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789"
```

I want to output the value of what a utf8 code is assigned to.

If a is 97 in the utf8 table. What function do I call to output the character 'a' if 97 is the utf8 code?

```
fmt.Println(aMess[0]) // outputs 97 how do I convert 97 to what it is assigned too?
```

Comment: Do you mean `string(97)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go use  [runes](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/runes) for such sort of operations where in other languages we would refer as **char**

If I understood your question correctly. In order to get the code of a char you can use a function like this:

```
func fromStringToRune(message string) {
    for _, r := range message {
        fmt.Println(r)
    }
}
```

and if you want to get the char based on it's code you can use a function like this:

```
func fromRuneToChar(r int) {
    fmt.Println(string(r))
}
```

Here is [Example](https://play.golang.org/p/PRP3KohmWMG) usage.

Comment: I hope you heard my facepalm from across the world, because I didn't even try casting with a string. I was trying to use the utf8.DecodeRune() functions to try to get this to work.

I just tried to rune cast it, and it gave me the same unicode value. Is there another datatype I can use instead of string just to not take up the four bytes in memory needed for a string variable/conversion? I know that is negligible, but I want to make my program as small as possible.

Comment: I think it depends on the specific use case, but in your case it seems a bit of an overkill. I would say though it's very sensible approach from your side, it just turns out that in this case there is much simpler solution. Cheers!

Comment: @Zthom Sorry, I'm not aware of such datatype. It seems kind of unlikely though. According to your specific context it may be more optimal to keep the data as `[]byte` or `[]rune` array, but I'm not sure it would be actual optimization.